# Stuck when executing grep in unix

Tags: unix, grep

after executing grep '19-12-2008 without ending the quote.i got stuck with > in command line
how to exit

Comment: what shell are you using?

Answer (score 12):

End it by closing your quote (i.e. typing another apostrophe).

Or, if you've changed your mind and you don't want to execute the command any more, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will get you out of the command and back into the shell.

Answer (score 5):

Just CTRL-C and start again, or type in <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the next line. The prompt you're seeing (`>`) is because you haven't finished the command - the shell thinks you wanted that linefeed within a string and it's waiting for you to close that string with another quote.

Comment: At least with `bash`/`grep`, it's not treating the linefeed as a literal.  `echo -en hi | grep 'h   '` (with single *or* double quotes, and with newlines instead of spaces) both pick up the `hi`.  If you actually put *spaces* in the quotes, it does not pick up the `hi`.

Comment: Interesting, that must be a grep feature - it works with `grep 'h<lf>i'` but echo outputs it as I expected, *with* an embedded linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

escape your quotation mark with a backslash

```
$ grep \'19-12-2008
```